# Mat Drawer overwrites default stylesettings Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I have a questioooon

Im using react and have global tailwind style classes in the index.html

```
text-neutral-900 bg-white dark:text-neutral-100 dark:bg-neutral-900 font-normal
```

Im trying to implement a Mat Drawer in my application, which shouldnt be a difficult task...

So I here is my drawer

```
<mat-drawer-container>
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" position="end">
    <p> Im content </p>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

the thing is, when wrapping the router outlet in the mat-drawer-contents, my styles get overwritten: without wrapping:

[image]

with wrapping:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the default styles of the Drawer overwrote my styles. So what I did to solve the problem was overwriting the default styles.

first adding class to the mat-drawer-container

```
<mat-drawer-container class="app-drawer">
```

& then adding my default styles in a css file, referring the specified class:

```
.app-drawer {
    // text-neutral-900
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(23 23 23 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
    // bg-white
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));

    // dark:text-neutral-100 
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
            --tw-text-opacity: 1;
            color: rgb(245 245 245 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
    }
    // dark:bg-neutral-900
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
            --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: rgb(23 23 23 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
        }
}
```